# Remove whitespace in dynamically generated input id using Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, whitespace

```
    input type="checkbox" class="btn pointCheck" 
    id="GasMeteringVC-VolumeCorrector-Temperature t"
    value="GasMeteringVC/VolumeCorrector/Temperature t">

    <label for="GasMeteringVC-VolumeCorrector-Temperature t" class="pointBefore"></label>
```

Could someone please help me in removing whitespace between Temperature and t.

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="btn pointCheck" id="{{../../name}}-{{../name}}-{{name}}"
                                                            value="{{../../name}}/{{../name}}/{{name}}"/>
                    <label for="{{../../name}}-{{../name}}-{{name}}" class="pointBefore">
```

Above is the handlebars code that generates a menu with checkboxes and labels for them. All the values are from the JSON object.

Comment: You need to give us more context. From what I see, the value of `{{name}}` is `Temperature t`. If you want your handlebars template model to be whitespace-free, then you have to clean your model variables before rendering...

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, it would probably be best to do this type of cleaning outside of your template. If, however, you choose to go that route, you can use a Helper.

### Register a helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('cleanConcat', function() {
    var argument        = null;
    var data            = null;
    var cleanedString   = '';
    var cleanedStrings  = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i ) {
        argument = arguments[ i ];

        // Handlebars passes in extra arguments, so you can't just loop through
        // arguments itself
        if ( typeof argument === 'object' && argument.name === 'cleanConcat' ) {
            data = argument.data.root;

            for ( var prop in data ) {

                // You can do any type of cleaning that you want here.
                // As an example I forced each string to lower case and replaced spaces with a "-"
                cleanedString = data[ prop ].toLowerCase().replace( /\s/g, '-' );
                cleanedStrings.push( cleanedString );
            }
            return cleanedStrings.join( '-' );
        }
    }
});
```

### Pass in any number of strings to that helper

```
<label for="{{cleanConcat ../../name ../name name}}"
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/U4ELK/1/